# how to limit to only on iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this in my jquery

```
$(document).on("click","div", function() {     
     console.log(event.target);     
});
```

this thing gets called 7 times per click. I want it to be called only once.

I tried doing this

```
$(document).on("click","div", function(){
    n = 0;
    if(n < 1){
        console.log(event.target);
    }
});
```

but that didnt help this is what I see

```
<div class="abc" id="abc_0"><span class="background-image"></span></div>
<div class="abc" id="abc_0"><span class="background-image"></span></div>
<div class="abc" id="abc_0"><span class="background-image"></span></div>
<div class="abc" id="abc_0"><span class="background-image"></span></div>
<div class="abc" id="abc_0"><span class="background-image"></span></div>
<div class="abc" id="abc_0"><span class="background-image"></span></div>
<div class="abc" id="abc_0"><span class="background-image"></span></div>
```

Comment: You need to post more information, without the markup the question is meaningless.

Comment: The symptoms are enough to diagnose the problem here.

Comment: To guess at a solution, sure. Regardless, OP should provide enough information so nobody has to guess.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Just use the id of the div. `$(document).on("click","#abc_0", function(){
    console.log(event.target);
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `#abc_0` is probably nested 7 `div`s deep, so the handler will be called for each of them.

If you only want it to execute for the target, try this:

```
$(document).on("click","div", function() {     
    if (this == event.target) { 
        console.log(event.target);     
    }
});
```

Or target something more specific than `"div"`

http://jsfiddle.net/q3pX8/

Comment: this answer is good. But the best way is to use http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: Wasn't aware that worked with event delegation. That is better.

Comment: I agree that @Reigel's solution is pretty useful. But I dislike the idea of attaching a click event to every single div. For me it is better to use a specific selector, in this case it could be the id since we don't know the logic of the rest of the code.

Comment: @Memochipan in this case I bet, it's not suitable to attach the event using `id`... I believe there are many similar divs considering how the id on that particular div is. It has a number on it. `#abc_0`, `#abc_1`, and so on..

Comment: @Reigel I used `id` just as an example since it is the most specific selector. It could be also a `:first-child`.  Anyway, I think your edited answer is more specific. Voted up!

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to stop the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

To do that you should use `event.stopPropagation();` like below

```
$(document).on("click","div", function(e) {    
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(event.target);     
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TuDBZ/)

---

EDIT:

I can see that you have a `class="abc"` on your div. Might as well be better to use that.

```
$(document).on("click",".abc", function(e) {    
    e.stopPropagation(); // you may not need this anymore
    console.log(event.target);     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the markup for the div being clicked with context? It looks like you have nested divs. So rightfully, it should log 7 times.

A better solution would be

```
$(document).on("click","#abc_0", function() {     
     console.log(event.target);     
});
```

---

Replication of problem http://jsfiddle.net/FBnM6/

Comment: I am aware of that solution but I cant use it for several reasons and I want to use what I asked in the question. Thanks

Comment: From the HTML the OP posted, I don't see any nested divs.

Comment: Ok, even worse then. OP didn't post any HTML at all.

Comment: Strange that you wouldn't be able to use ID reference. That's the point of unique descriptors in the first place. See Jason P's answer otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(document).on('click', 'div', function (event) {
    If (event.handled) return;
    event.handled = true;
    //your code
});
```

Comment: I am using mobile device to post this answer. Pls seperate code lines

Answer (score 0):

Considering Jason P's answer I changed my answer, I think is better to use just a specific selector, **for example** use the id:

```
$(document).on("click","#abc_0", function(){
    console.log(event.target);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nDe9X/ (Enable the console in your browser).

That way you are not triggering all the nested divs.